# Convert C# to VB.NET: Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i found a solution to my problem in github here
https://github.com/brandon-barker/PushBots.NET
but in C#, I tried to convert it in many site but they all throw error 
here's the original C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using PushBots.NET;
using PushBots.NET.Models;
using PushBots.NET.Enums;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Run().Wait();
        }
        static async Task Run()
        {
            var client = new PushBotsClient("55165801f85f8b457d", "b03052506824b4f3165ecc0");
            var pushMessage = new BatchPush()
            {
                Message = "new Test from API",
                Badge = "+1",
                Platforms = new[] { Platform.Android, Platform.iOS }
            };
            var result = await client.Push(pushMessage);
        }
}
```

it work fine but when i convert the static async Task Run() to VB i get alot of error here's the code in VB

```
Private Shared Function Run() As Task
    Dim client = New PushBotsClient("55165801f85f8b457d", "b03052506824b4f3165ecc0")
Dim pushMessage = New BatchPush() With { _
    Key .Message = "new Test from API", _
    Key .Badge = "+1", _
    Key .Platforms = New () {Platform.Android, Platform.iOS} _
}
    Dim result = Await client.Push(pushMessage)
End Function
```

the error i'm getting is on Key
(Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.)

2nd error is with Await
(Await can only be used within an Async method)

Comment: Have you tried adding `Async`?  `Private Shared Async Function Run() As Task`

Comment: In addition to adding `Async` to the function declaration, remove `Key` from the statements inside the `With`

Comment: Also take out the `Key` words - those are only used for _anonymous_ types, but you are creating a named type (`BatchPush`)

Comment: Also, replace "New () {Platform.Android, Platform.iOS}" with "{Platform.Android, Platform.iOS}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to fix:

- Add `Async` in the method declaration:

  ```
  Private Shared Async Function Run() As Task
  ```
- Remove `Key` from the `With` block. Adding `Key` during the C#->VB conversion is [correct for anonymous classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx), but not for non-anonymous class property initializations.

  In other words,
  C# `new { ID = 3 }` corresponds to VB `New With { Key .ID = 3 }`, but
  C# `new MyClass { ID = 3 }` should become `New MyClass With { .ID = 3 }`.
- `New()` is not required for implicitly typed arrays, i.e. `.Platforms = {Platform.Android, Platform.iOS}` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Async` to your function signature.

```
Private Shared Async Function Run() As Task
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191564.aspx